# Copying to clipboard using javascript/flash

Tags: javascript, flash, clipboard

I am currently working on a PHP/HTML/Javascript project and I am trying to automatically copy text to the user clipboard when they press a button.

I've done some research and found that this can be done easily in IE, but every other browser doesn't support this, so instead a flash file is embedded which does the copying. Howver, this doesn't seem to be working.

Below is the code that does the copying

```
function copyToClipboard()
{
    //Copy to clipbord if IE
    if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData)
    {
        window.clipboardData.setData('text', 'I am copied');
    }
    else //other browsers
    {
        alert("other browser");
        var flashcopier = 'flashcopier';
        if(!document.getElementById(flashcopier)) {
            var divholder = document.createElement('div');
            divholder.id = flashcopier;
            document.body.appendChild(divholder);
        }
        document.getElementById(flashcopier).innerHTML = '';
        var divinfo = '<embed src="_clipboard.swf" FlashVars="clipboard='+encodeURIComponent('other browser copied')+'" width="0" height="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>';
        document.getElementById(flashcopier).innerHTML = divinfo;
    }
}
```

It appears to be working fine when using IE, but when using Chrome, nothing gets copied to the clipboard. There aren't any errors either in the chrome development tools.

I know the flash file is embedded OK using the above code as, if I change the src to say `clipboard.swf_rubbish` then the chrome development console says its can't find the file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

That solution no longer works with the release of Flash Player 10. Because of security restrictions on accessing clipboard data. You can find a workaround [here](http://www.rodsdot.com/javascript/cross_browser_clipboard_copy_with_pop_over_message.asp)